# date and time to just time in python

Tags: python, date, time, pyephem

I have made a small program for my weather station in python and its all working perfectly, but I have one little problem.

The output displays as

```
2014/5/18 04:03:41
2014/5/18 19:47:41
```

I want it to display as

```
04:03:41
19:47:41
```

Is there any easy way to do this,I was thinking of just stripping the characters out but it sounds more of a bodge than converting.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Is the output just a string, or a `datetime` object, or...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [66]: t="2014/5/18 19:47:41".split()

In [67]: print t[-1]
19:47:41
```

If you have a string just split and get the last element which is the time.

```
t="2014/5/18 04:03:41"
from datetime import datetime
str_time= datetime.strptime(t,'2014/5/18  %H:%M:%S').time()
In [72]: print str_time
04:03:41
```

[datetime docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)